# Populate 3 combobox from same table but use filter in all 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

i have a windows application having 3 combobox. username, prepared by, authorized by.
 i want name of all employees in user name whereas in prepared by and authorized by i want selected names but from the same table. so i have assigned roles in the employee table which is an integer value and fired a stroed procedure. i cannot populate the combobox

SQL:

```
emp table:
create table emp1
(
    employee_id int constraint pk_employee_id_employee primary key not null,
    un_id varchar(10) constraint uk_un_id_employee unique not null,
    fname varchar(20) not null,
    lname varchar(20) not null,
    roles int not null
)

stored procedure:
alter proc rolecombo
(
    @roles int  
)
as begin
select * from emp1 where roles<@roles
end
```

C# code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "rolecombo";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roles",comboBox3.SelectedValue);
            adp.Fill(dsautho, "emp1");
            comboBox3.DataSource = dsautho.Tables["emp1"];
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "fname";
            comboBox3.ValueMember = "employee_id";
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
            con.Close();
}
```

Comment: why you use this code. comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;? this doesn't make sense

Comment: so that initially when the form loads there is no value or item displayed in the combobox

Comment: did u get any exception. ? Cannot bind to the new display member.
Parameter name: newDisplayMember

Comment: change the Line of code  comboBox3.DataSource = dsautho.Tables["emp1"]; to comboBox3.DataSource = dsautho.Tables[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Sample Code:

```
public static DataSet DownDataBind()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=S1B01689;Initial Catalog=CosmosDB;User Id=sa;Password=Nttdata123");
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,categName from CM_Categories",conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds);

        adapter.Dispose();

        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        string s = exp.Message.ToString();
        return null;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = DownDataBind();
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];// use Tables[0] instead of Table Name
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategName";
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;         
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: use dsautho.Tables[0] Instead of dsautho.Tables["emp1"]; It works fine